# Can I switch iron-pages programmatically in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

Is there anyway how can I switch iron-pages programmatically in Polymer? My point is I want to redirect page when action is done in Polymer.

I know, I can redirect by using `window.location.href` but need to know switch iron-pages in polymer programmatically.

```
_responseChanged: function(response) {
  console.log('response', response.applicationId);

  /*
    I want to redirect page here
  */

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are three ways in which you can do that

- Call `selectNext` function which will always select next page
- Call `select` function and pass the page number that you want to be selected
- You can also directly change the `selected` property of iron-pages(not covered below)

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<dom-module id="iron-page-select">
  <template>
    <style></style>
    <iron-pages id="pages" selected="0">
      <div on-tap="_selectNext">tap me to change to next page</div>
      <div on-tap="_selectCustom">tap me to change to 4th page</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
    </iron-pages>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'iron-page-select',
    _selectNext: function() {
      this.$.pages.selectNext();
    },

    _selectCustom: function() {
      this.$.pages.select(3);
    }
  })
</script>


<iron-page-select></iron-page-select>
```

Comment: How can I put query parameter there?

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: `/mypage-success/12342233` I want to add `12342233` as parameters.

Comment: Are you using `app-route`?

Comment: yap, sure. I'm using.

Comment: In that case you can create a `observer` on `data` property of `app-route` and from there call the `select` function of `iron-pages`